# Next File in the DIR does not open

Tags: vba, sendkeys

All my sendkeys execute properly and the document saves and closes but then the next document does not Open. Before I added the sendkeys, the documents in the DIR would each open but now the next document will not. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Password()
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long
Dim Password As String
Dim fileName As Variant
With Sheet1
LastRow = .Range("C9999").End(xlUp).Row
fileName = Dir("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\*.pdf")


Do While fileName <> ""

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\" & fileName)
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00005
    For CustRow = 2 To LastRow
    Password = .Range("C" & CustRow).Value

    Application.SendKeys "{F6}", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys Password, True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
    Application.SendKeys "(~)", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys Password, True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
    Application.SendKeys "(~)", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "(~)", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "^(s)", True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

    fileName = Dir
    Next CustRow
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `fileName = Dir` should be just before `Loop`, not inside the `CustRow` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made the suggested change but the next file does not open. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Is the second file even found?  What happens when it gets to that point?

Comment: I tried taking out the sendkeys and leaving everything the same and it opened each file in the directory. When I leave the sendkeys in, it closes the first pdf after saving and then just continues to run but nothing actually happens.

Comment: Any sendkeys command causes the next file not to open

Comment: Add `Debug.Print fileName` just after the `Do While` line, then run with and without the sendkeys - how does the out put differ?

Comment: Ouput is the same as the output without `SendKeys` when I do not include the debug statement

Comment: It looks like it is the wait now that is causing the problem not the sendkeys